# When submitting bug report with iOS app, iPhone 7 not recognized as device?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I found this little bug in the bug report section of the app, on iPhone 7, it says the device is unknown. Here is a picture to demonstrate this issue:

[image: Bug]

It doesn't really affect use but it will be a little more convenient when submitting but reports with the new iPhone 7 after fixing this bug.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.1 (Build 14B67)

Comment: `iPhone9,4` is the correct code for the 7 Plus so that part is correct, there just needs to be some new platform strings added (which are only really there to prevent confusion I guess, you already know what it is from the `iPhone9,4`)

Comment: @Cai I know, that is what I'm asking for

Comment: I know, I'm not disagreeing with you. Just pointing out that the information is still there. (Actually I though the "`iPhone9,4`" was usually left in but I just checked and seems I'm remembering incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

I had thought I added the iPhone 7, but I only added support for Verizon and Sprint (CDMA) models, not ATT and T-Mobile (GSM) models.  See https://github.com/erichoracek/UIDevice-Hardware/pull/18

Interestingly, when I had a 4S, they had CDMA-only and GSM-only models, but my 6 and 6S supported both CDMA and GSM.  I guess they needed a little more space for all the new features or something.