# iOS app can't detect iPad Pro device name properly

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

My new iPad version is Pro 10.5", and the Stack Exchange iOS app is unable to properly detect that device. See below:

> [image: Info block]

Comment: Another bug reports with same issue for old devices perceived helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285440 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265946

Comment: No downvote from me, but it might really be in the "too minor to care" category for others. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard my point of view consider downvote for bug (any, even a minor) as "it's not bug at all, no need to do something with it". Am I wrong?

Comment: Totally right, I downvote bugs when they're not bugs... but other people think in different ways. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard very sad.

Comment: @ShadowWizard should we bring shame on all edit approvers? :)

Comment: Heh, well if @iBug's quote in his answer is correct then it's indeed not a bug, but we can't know until he links to the source. If he just throw a guess, it can still be a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard he told about "fixing", so ... how it can be fixed if it's not a bug? :) I think holding app device DB in consistency with a currently released devices - is a "must" for app. iPad Pro 10.5" was released on 14 June. Current app version (1.7.0.1) on July 15. Whole month to add ability to recognize this device. Hence it's a bug :)

Comment: Answer updated. I added quotation from SO.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the Stack Exchange app or SE server knows the **name** of your device. They can only get the model number, which is `iPad7,3`. All apps that do "device identification" have their own databases of display names mapper. So the bug is simply because that:

Your device is too new. SE doesn't have a record of that by far. It'll be fixed as soon as SE adds a mapper entry to map `iPad7,3` to "iPad Pro 10.5-inch (Wi-Fi)".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/5958455) on SO provides a clue: Yeah, no marketing (display) name is available, you need a DB by yourself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27836910/5958455) suggests that it's the same for Android.

Apps only get model numbers and manufacturers. They must build a database of display names by themselves.

Comment: Where did you get the quote from? Please edit and link to the source. If it's not official and just a guess, better remove the quote formatting as it's confusing.

Comment: My guess is that the app uses a not-up-to-date version of one of the snippets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26028918/4751173).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated. Added quotation from SO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Anyway, with a little experience with a device you'll know that it's right.