# Stack Exchange app iPhone X optimization

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app, iphone

The Stack Exchange app doesn’t look very good on Apple’s brand new flagship phone yet.

[image: iPhone X Screenshot]

Also the app can’t identify the device model either. (Says Unknown (iPhone 10,3))

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone X (iPhone10,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.1 (Build 15B93)

Comment: Yeah, there are a couple of general problems with iOS 11 coherence... and, while the team working on the app is trying to keep up with bugs, I'm not sure how much time they have to make it fit a new form factor.

Comment: Related (and downvoted too) [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299212/339911) about device detection. Don't know why people downvote such posts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TL;DR: When active app development resumes, this will be a top priority, but there's really no timeline for when that will happen.

Unfortunately, even for an app like ours which supports a wide variety of screen sizes and configurations, updating to the iPhone X will be a major undertaking.  Not only do every screen edge hugging elements (e.g., the draft indicator) need to be revisited but every screen needs to be tested in portrait and landscape.  I've estimated bare-bones support for X as a 2 month project, but given current product priorities that's no target start-date for the project.

The good news is there's really no path forward with iOS development that doesn't involve supporting the X, so when development resumes it'll need to be the top priority.

Comment: Is it on github as open source or is this in house?

Comment: @Nickpick In house.

Comment: "when development resumes".it hopefully resumes soon. This app should be on github!

Comment: Please update support for DynamicType; currently it's absent or results in much smaller fonts compared to Apple apps. Should I post a separate question (feature request) for that?

Comment: @yurkennis That should be its own question and is definitely something worth looking at.  The app does support DynamicType but when we adopted it the `.body` font type that works for Mail was just way too big for an iPhone 4s, so we scaled things down 15%.  Now that phones are so much bigger it's worth re-examining.

Comment: Has there been any thought given to making the app open-source? Seems like at least a couple people would be interested in taking on tasks like this, but maybe managing the open source project is more of a burden than you’d like...

Comment: Any updates? I believe it has been a year or so since this response.

Comment: Open source it.

Comment: Any update on this? It's been two years.

Comment: @johan The apps are no longer supported. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/334566

Comment: Really a pity that this app appears now completely abandoned for more than 3 years. Either kill it or open source it, but currently this seems like a failure on the management side of stackexchange.