# All links are not clickable in the post when commenting in iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, hyperlinks

When commenting edit box is opened on some post, the all links in such post are not clickable in iOS app. For example:

> [image: link comment]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 12.0 (Build 16A366)

Comment: iPad7,3 means iPad Pro (10.5 inch, WiFi)

Comment: @astonearachnid alredy reported about year ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299212

Comment: Didn't realize that was auto generated